# UICollectionViewDelegate не вызывается didDeselectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c

В проекте нет ни одного `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Множественное выделение разрешено `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES`
Почему метод `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` вызывается только при долгом нажатии ячейки? Это так и задумано? При обычном нажатии вызывается `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`даже если ячейка уже выделена.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    //работа с данными, вызов перезагрузки ячейки для обновления внешнего вида
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    //работа с данными, вызов перезагрузки ячейки для обновления внешнего вида
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй сбросить выделение ячейки (даже если его не видно) вот через такой хак:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selected = YES;
    [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: добавил в `cellForItemAtIndexPath` код `if ([self isDateSelected:date]) {
        cell.selected = YES;
        [self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    } else {
        cell.selected = NO;
        [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }` - работает, но странно, почему приходится использовать этот хак